# std::map iterator difference between (*pos).second and pos->second

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have some legacy code which uses (*pos).second to get a structure:

```
std::map<std::string, TMyStruct> TMyStructMap;

TMyStructMap  infoMap;
TMyStructMap::const_iterator pos = infoMap.begin();

// then later somewhere

TMyStruct x = (*pos).second;
```

Isn't this the same as: `TMyStruct x = pos->second` ?

If so, any advantage or style reason for doing one over the other?

Comment: @Wikiti C has no iterators afaik

Comment: @Wikiti I would agree except the operators can be overloaded in C++ so the behavior could be different.  I would expect them to be the same in any sane implementation though.

Comment: @NathanOliver You're right. Unless `->` and `*` are overloaded, the behaviour should be exactly the same.

Comment: @NathanOliver your statement isn't strong enough. If `* .` and `->` behave differently, the implementation is broken.